# Crafting the most efficient Rails 3 has_many :through query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have two Rails 3 models, `Product` and `Room` defined per below. Each Room can have multiple products, and each Product can be in multiple rooms:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :rooms, :through => :product_selection
  has_many :product_selection
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :products, :through => :product_selection
  has_many :product_selection
end

class ProductSelection < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :room
end
```

I'd like to create a query within `rooms_controller.rb` to return records for the first 10 rooms, and for each Room include a count of the number of products pushed to that room (to find out how many products are in each Room) and a sum of a column within Product called `cost` for all products in the Room (to get the total cost of all the products in the room). After calling the query, I would ideally be able to call `@rooms[i].total_products` and `@rooms[i].total_cost` (or something similar) along with the Room fields so it can be easily digested and iterated by a template.

I know I could create 10 different calls then loop through each as @room.products.count and @room.products.sum(cost), but there has to be a more efficient way...and I have a feeling I'm overlooking something obvious.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The naive implementation will have you do N+1 queries...

If your desire was to just count your products efficiently, I would suggest implementing a [:counter_cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Though as you also want to perform a calculation (summation on cost), eager loading the products with the rooms query will be more desirable.  The idea being to return your list of rooms and their products.

```
room_array = Room.includes(:products).limit(10)
```

If there was the further desire to make this efficient, you may want to have the database do the summation, too.